# How to get AWS credentials with a UserPools idToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Im currently using a USER-POOLS authorizer to get the first 3 tokens for my API:

- idToken
- refreshToken
- accessToken

From here I would like to request credentials to be able to SigV4 request to my already set up API gateway, but first I need to get the requested credentials in order to do the SigV4.

In the docs I found this:

```
// Set the region where your identity pool exists (us-east-1, eu-west-1)
AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';

// Configure the credentials provider to use your identity pool
AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:009xxxx ...',
});

// Make the call to obtain credentials
AWSCognito.config.credentials.get(function(){

  // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
  var accessKeyId = AWSCognito.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
  var secretAccessKey = AWSCognito.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
  var sessionToken = AWSCognito.config.credentials.sessionToken;

});
```

To my surprise, the callback is called but the values for the 
- accessKeyId
- secretAccessKey
- sessionToken
are all null.

I was expecting some kind of method, where I send my first idToken, and based on that I get the credentials, but it looks like this is all figured out under the hood?, anyways it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I realised that there is an undocumented way of doing this.

You need to construct this object first:

```
let url = 'cognito-idp.' + 'identity pool region' + '.amazonaws.com/' + 'your user pool id';
let logins = {};

logins[url] = idTokenJwt; // <- the one obtained before

let params = {
   IdentityPoolId: 'the federated identity pool id', 
   Logins: logins
};

let creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);


AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = creds;

creds.get(function (err: any) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("returned without error"); // <-- this gets called!!!

    // and the values are correctly set!
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

  }
  else{
    console.log("returned with error"); // <-- might get called if something is missing, anyways self-descriptive. 
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

In my case I still had to configure the trust relationship between the role and the identity pool, here the example:

```
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "your federated identity pool id"
    },
    "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
      "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
    }
  }
}
```

*You can also replace "authenticated" with "unauthenticated", "graph.facebook.com", "google ...", depending your needs.